# How can I install "Python Editor" on "Ubuntu Bash" in Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10, editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install a "python editor" that I can use for the Python 2.7 installation I've done via Bash Ubuntu in Windows 10.

I understand that the trick is to get a connection between "windows 10" desktop and the bash Ubuntu environment.

[More info about "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but you do know Idle (python IDE) installs with python on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you store your Python files in Windows, for example c:\dev\dev\pythonapp..., then you can edit them using whatever code editor you prefer (e.g. VS Code, Visual Studio, JetBrains PyCharm, Sublime, etc.) and you can then run your Python scripts from both Windows, and Bash (via /mnt/c/dev/pythonapp).

HTH.